# CSS how change cursor in ::after on IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Works great in Chrome,
but how to do this in IE?

```
.someClass {
    cursor: default;
}
.someClass::after {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: yellow;
    content: 'someText';
}

<div class='someClass'>someDiv</div>
```

[sandbox](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FUBKEO1Y9ZLC)

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=content

Comment: I would be helpful to confirm which IE version you're testing with.

Comment: it works for me in IE what version do you use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out this solution. It's working on IE and other browsers.

```css
div.someClass{
    font-size:1em;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
div.someClass > span{
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-left: 6px;
}
div.someClass > span::after{
    content:'someText';    
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:right;
    background : yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class='someClass'>someDIV<span></span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

some older Browsers need a single colon instead of double colons. try `div > span:after`